# Call controller method from vuejs laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, controller

I'm working on laravel and vueJS.

I'm trying to call a function inside my controller from my view and I'm getting an error

Here's the function inside the controller

```
public function findit(int $ids) {
    $results = DB::select('select * from demande_traitements where id = ?', $ids);
    foreach($results as $post) {
        return $post->traiter;
    }
}
```

I defined this

```
use \App\Http\Controllers\MissioneController;`
```

And this is how I'm calling it :

{{ MissioneController::findit($Missione.id) }}

And here's the error that I'm getting :

```
  - invalid expression: missing ) after argument list in

"\n\n                  \t\t"+_s(MissioneController::findit($Missione.id))+"\n\n                  "
```

Raw expression: {{ MissioneController::findit($Missione.id) }}

Comment: what's matters with vue.js? Maybe you should use RESTful style for your code.

Answer (score 0):

**routes/web.php**

```php
Route::resource('traitements', 'TraitementsController');
```

**app/Http/Controllers/DemandeTraitementsController**

```php
use App\DemandeTraitement as Traitement;
..

public function show(Traitement $traitement){
    return view('traitements.show',compact('traitement'));
}
```

**resources/view/traitements/show.blade.php**

```php
<div>{{ $traitement }}</div>

<script>
const app = Vue({
    data(){
        return {
            traitement: {{ json_encode($traitement) }}
        }
    }
});
</script>
```